# How to set Scheduled alarms in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to coding and I am working on an application that makes an alarms at a certain date and time beforehand, but I started one alarm but it does not work

I will be more thankful, if you could help me on how to Solve the problem

this MainActivity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)   
    var alarmMgr: AlarmManager? = null
    lateinit var alarmIntent: PendingIntent

    alarmMgr = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    alarmIntent = Intent(this, myBroadcastReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)
    }


    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {


        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5)

        set(Calendar.MINUTE, 12)
    }


    alarmMgr?.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        1000 * 60 * 20,
        alarmIntent
    )
    alarmMgr?.cancel(alarmIntent)

       val receiver = ComponentName(this,      myBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

    this.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        receiver,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
    )
```

this myBroadcastReceiver:

```
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {

    if (p1!!.action.equals("com.tester.alarmmanager")){

        val  Newintent2 = Intent(p0!!,ShowAct::class.java)

        p0!!.startActivity(Newintent2)

    }
}
```

in AndroidManifest:

i used 3 uses-permission
and receiver

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" >     </uses-permission>
     <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"></uses-permission>

  <receiver
            android:name=".myBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            >

         <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.tester.alarmmanager"></action>

         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: "it does not work" is a quite vague description of the problem. If you want an answer, you'd better tag your question with android since it's an android question (I've done it for you), and describe the problem **precisely**: what are you doing, what do you expect to happen, what happens instead.

Comment: alarmMgr?.cancel(alarmIntent) what is this? why're you cancelling it right after creating the alarm.

Comment: thank you.I am new to Android development I was following a lesson about alarmThere was no voice to explain and I quoted the code as it is , but when i delete alarmMgr?.cancel not work

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `alarmMgr?.cancel(alarmIntent)` you're cancelling alarm right after it's creation.

Comment: thak you . i delete alarmMgr?.cancel(alarmIntent)  But still does not work

Comment: when   println("this hour${Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY}")
        println("this minute ${Calendar.MINUTE}").    not same Emulator time Does not change this hour11 and this minute 12